# How do I use the geometry nodes group input texture type

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using blender 3.1.0 alpha, and I want to use the same noise texture I am using somewhere else, in my geometry nodes setup. I noticed that there was an option to change an input type to Texture:

[image: Texture input¨]

but I have yet to find a way to connect this to a node in a way where it actually does anything, all the nodes I connect it to just give me a red noodle:

[image: Red noodle]

So I was wondering, how is this input supposed to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the only node that takes the Texture type as an Input is the [Attribute Sample Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_sample_texture.html) node (note the node interface has not been updated in the documentation).

It's deprecated starting on 3.0 but for backwards-compatibility (I guess) will be kept around at least until 3.1. You can enable legacy nodes (that is to say nodes from 2.93 version which are not officially released in 3.0+) by going Edit > Preferences > Interface > Developer Extras and then Edit > Preferences > Experimental > Debugging > Geometry Nodes Legacy.

It should not be mistaken for an Image data type which goes into an Image Texture node. The input discs are purple but the Texture one is more pink than the Image type.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so I guess it is just there for backwards compatibility, I guess there is not really any way to get outside textures into geometry nodes then.

Comment: No, not yet but I'm sure it will see other uses down the line when they extend the features.

Comment: Developer direction is apparently to remove it in favour of texture nodes and image inputs, actually: https://developer.blender.org/T95461.